# Create a CSV using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a method which is returning a list of data based on some conditions.

example:

```
source_image = cv2.imread("images/source_test.tif")
target_image= cv2.imread("images/target_test.tif")
total_matching_points =998
if total_matching_points > 500:
    generateTargetCSV(source_image, target_image, total_matching_points)
```

Now I need to create a CSV under method where it will store all the values passed in parameter:

```
def generateTargetCSV(source, target, total_matching_points):
#Need help here to create a csv where it will store all the values coming from above arguments///
    df = pd.DataFrame(source, target, total_matching_points)
    df.to_csv('some_value.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What is the problem, what error are you getting?

Comment: What values are in source, target, total matching points?

Comment: Hi @Tarik just string in source and target and a numberic value in tatal matching point example :
source_image = cv2.imread("images/test.tif")
target_image = cv2.imread("images/test2.tif")
total_matching_points =987

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are passing lists into the method, to create a pandas df you should do

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'source':source, 'target':target, 'total_matching_points': total_matching_points})
```

You can then save with

```
df.to_csv(location+filename, index=(Boolean))
```